# How to add specific view to uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `PersonCell` with `xib` and `.h`, `.m` files and person's characteristics. So, depending on `PersonCell.state`, I want to show different number and kind of characteristics.

I want to use a specific `Parameterview` with `titleLabel` and `constantLabel`, so i can add those parameterViews with `for-in array`. I can't use `constraints` in code, coz of cell `reuse`.

How to do that? I see only stupid way - add every characteristic view to `PersonCell` and depending on the state, show and hide them. But there are 50+ different characteristics.

Comment: The way to cope with reuse is not show and hide but add and remove (or reuse, of course). Thus there will be only one in each cell, just as you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try use a `tableView` instead of the array of views. For example, the `PersonCell` could have a tableView inside, where each cell contains a `ParameterView`.

From the array you already have, you could implement `UITableViewDataSource` in the `PersonCell`. I think this would be a pretty simple solution when the `PersonCell` depends so much on the state.

Let me know if you have questions or you need more specific information.

Comment: This is the best way to implement such things

Comment: Thanks, @Catalina T. If I want those views horizontally, do i need to use UICollectionView instead tableview?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, a collectionView would be the best way to go about it.